# Does django-compressor work with template inheritance?

Tags: django, compression, django-compressor

I'm using [django-compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to compress my site's static CSS and Javascript files. Since I serve my site's static assets via Amazon S3, I'm also using [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to upload my files to S3.

Here's my issue: I'm trying to make a clean `base.html` template that all my site's other templates can inherit and extend. Here's what it looks like currently:

```
{% load compress %}

<html>
 <head>
  <!-- test -->
  {% compress css %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css" />
  {% endcompress %}

  {% compress css %}
  {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  {% endcompress %}

  {% compress js %}
  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
  {% endcompress %}
 </head>
 <body>
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, what I'm **attempting** to do here is allow my templates that inherit this template to override the `css` and `js` blocks, so they can define their own css and javascript to be compressed. Unfortunately, that's not what happens.

When I run `python manage.py compress` (to have django-compressor analyze my templates and generated the compressed javascript and css code), it doesn't actually find my included css and javascript files.

For instance, here's my site's `index.html` template:

```
{% block css %}
 {{ block.super }}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/index.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

When I attempt to visit that page on my site, I get an error saying that the compressed file doesn't exist.

I believe that what's happening is that the `python manage.py compress` command isn't inspecting my templates that inherit from `base.html`. And since it isn't analyzing them, it isn't generating any compressed code.

I'd really like to get this working, because the only workaround I've found so far is to manually add `{% compress %}...{% endcompress %}` tags in every single template file I have explicitly. I just hate to do that since it repeats so much code everywhere :(

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like the problem is as the error specifies: does the file exist on the local filesystem? Remember with S3, you have to set up the storage to save locally as well as as remotely.

Comment: I'm currently doing that as the django-compressor docs suggest, via the custom CachedS3BotoStorage class. This part works fine (eg: if I'm not attempting to compress a {% block %}..{% endblock %} snippet). Also: I get no errors when I actually run the `python manage.py compress` management command--only when I actually attempt to view a page that inherits from `base.html` and overrides the css or js blocks.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using offline compression, in which case the template inheritance does not work as one would expect. See these issues relevant to this "problem":

- https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/171
- https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/175