# Django Compressor Offline Inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, offline, django-compressor

This issue is specifically for a production site using Django Compressor. I want this to work when COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True so that I can pre-compress all of my site's css files before pushing to production.

I would like to, within base.html, do the equivalent of this:

```
{% compress %}
    {% block css %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}
```

so that all of my css blocks in files that extend base are compressed. This is mainly so that I don't have to add {% compress %} tags to all my child templates.

There are several similar issues on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a good solution for doing this when compressing offline (i.e. with Django Compressor's compress management command). The surrounding compress tags work fine when COMPRESS_OFFLINE = False. Has someone found a way to make this work offline?

I'm listing a few similar threads that seem to pertain to non-offline solutions. The links in the second thread indicate that there have been past issues with inheritance when working with Django Compressor offline but perhaps they have been resolved:

[Django-compressor and template inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206146/django-compressor-and-template-inheritance)

[Does django-compressor work with template inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559018/does-django-compressor-work-with-template-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You have do use compress offline for that technique to work, but as long as you have caching set up properly, django-compressor will not re-compress on every request unless the resources have been changed.

I've used this technique to allow users to use [lesscss](http://lesscss.org) to extend the site theme and use our mixins etc. It's a little wonky to get working but (in my experience so far) it's perfectly stable when configured correctly, and doesn't introduce a substantial request latency once it's compressed the first time.

You can set up a service like [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com), [blamestella](https://www.blamestella.com), or [new relic](http://newrelic.com) to hit various pages to ensure the compressed assets are always in cache (they monitor for uptime, but work for this as well)